# running sudo on wsl.exe commands

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed via WSL2 and am able to run commands in that Ubuntu instance by doing `wsl.exe ls -latr` in PowerShell. But what if I wanted to run a command that required sudo? If I try `wsl.exe sudo whatever` I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: sudo whatever: No such file or directory
```

I guess there's also the problem of getting sudo to accept a PW via the CLI but there are [ways to deal with that](https://bitmingw.com/2017/01/22/use-sudo-in-scripts/).

Any ideas?